# open_basedir in linux plesk error

Tags: php, linux, plesk, open-basedir

I am trying to load a script from another webspace in plesk. I enabled open_basedir in the webspace and in my script I insert

```
include "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/";
```

However this is not working and I receive the following errors in log:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/eshop): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/test.example.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 2

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app): failed to open stream: No such device in /var/www/vhosts/test.example.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 2


mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/app/' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/test.example.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 2
```

I assume that it has to do with the fact that I am writing the path in a wrong way but I cant understand what is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of files of another subscription are owned by another system user. 
It's better to place necessary code in same subscription or in some shared place like `/usr/share/pear` or `/usr/share/php`:

[image: plesk php include_path]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ll try that!

Comment: Oleg I placed the code in share place but still no luck. Should I give any special permissions or smth? I receive this: No input file specified.

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos Check "include_path" in domain's PHP settings as in screenshot.

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos Could you please provide error message which you get now?

Comment: Thanks I ll try that also. What I need to achieve is this: My code is at subdomain1.example.com and I want to be able to access it from subdomain2.example.com and also to be able to upload pics in a folder of subdomain2. What would be the best logic to follow?I thought also the solution of the redirection and to make the code of subdomain1 to have access to subdomain2. I suppose the include_path option is at subdomain2?

Comment: Could you please share the code which performs inclusion?

Comment: `include ("/usr/share/php5/myapp/");` (I have no pear folder but I have a php folder which I tried that also)

Comment: I've suppose you want inlude some php file, try following code: include("/usr/share/php5/myapp/somefile.php");

Comment: Thank you Oleg it worked! I had to put it also in the include_path 
in php settings